# MonkeyRunner::How to install python modules?

Tags: python, monkeyrunner

I am using MonkeyRunner to automate some UI test cases.
I need to collect logs from the device using tool like QXDM.
I see that win32com python module can be used to launch QXDM and collecting logs.
But when i use `from win32com.client import Dispatch` in python script which is passed as argument to MonkeyRunner, MonkeyRunner throws:

> "Import Error: No Module named win32com".

I have installed win32com on my machine, and when i use win32com in a python script which ran using "python test.py" its working fine.
Do we need to install win32com python module on Android device also? or what need to be done to make this work?

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this? I want to use my modules in other py classes. However, monkeyrunner throwing "No module found" error. Can  you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Monkeyrunner use Jython as its Python interface (jython.jar under tools\lib folder).
It uses 2.5.0 version. Now the latest Jython version is 2.5.2.

Either one does not support pywin32 or any other modules. It only supports standard Python modules in version 2.5.